# Algorithm: Identifying Duplicate Child Sets Across Levels of Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Say I have the following:

```
   _____W_____
  |     |     |
 _T_   _L_   _X_
|   | |   | |   |
A   B A   B A   B
```

As you can see, it is a standard tree (not a binary tree, as evidenced by the fact that `W` has three children). My goal is to identify the fact that the `A B` child sequence is repeated across the entire bottom level.

In more general terms, I want to be able to, starting at the root of a tree, look at the child subtree sets of my children (grandchildren sub-tree sets, essentially) and determine if they are identical all the way across the tree level, then recurse to my children and do the same at each of their smaller scopes. Rinse, repeat, all the way to the bottom of the overall tree.

A simplistic solution I've thought up would be to do a breadth-first (or depth-first) traversal of each sub-tree (in this case, `T`, `L`, and `X`) and comparing the words I come up with (minus the first character). A breadth-first traversal in this case would yield `TAB`, `LAB`, and `XAB`, and ignoring the first character, I would see that they're all `AB`. But imagine if the tree is instead the following:

```
   _____W_____
  |     |     |
 _T_   _L_   _X_
|   | |   | |   |
A   B Q   B A   B
```

It would be far more efficient to be able to grab the first `A`, then that `Q`, realize that they are not the same and that there is no point in continuing the search, and short-circuiting out.

I am mostly looking to see if there's some "obvious" algorithm that could be applied here, or, perhaps, an algorithm created for this specific problem; either of which I have never seen, cannot find, and/or don't know how to search for.

(I also marked this question with the "Java" tag, simply because my actual implementation of this tree structure [and other algorithms I am applying to it and do *not* have unanswered questions about] happen to be in that language. I can translate pseudocode, as well.)

**Edit** - This might make more sense as some example steps on the first tree above:

- Start at `W` (the root).
- Do I have 2 or more children? In this case, yes, 3: `T`, `L`, `X`.
- Compare `T`, `L`, and `X`'s child sub-trees.
- Are `T`, `L`, and `X`'s sets of child sub-trees the same across the **entire** level **at `W`'s scope**? In this case, yes, it's `A B` all the way across. In the second tree above, the answer is no, because that `Q` messes things up.
- Now drop down to `W`'s children, `T`, `L`, and `X`. Repeat the previous steps from above. Does `T` have 2 or more children? Yes, `A` and `B`. Do they have children? In the examples above, no, so there's nothing more to do. But imagine `A` and `B` are entire sub-trees, with children, grandchildren, etc. Now the question would be: Are these sub-trees the same across the **entire** level **at `T`'s scope**? So is `A son of T`'s set of child sub-trees identical to `B son of T`'s set of child sub-trees?

Comment: Help me understand the generalization you're after. Do you always want to compare the elements at level 3? All the leaf sets of the children direct of the root? Or something else?

Comment: @jacobm Added an edit with a (hopefully) more clear step-through of the idea.

Comment: So to be clear: it seems like you want to determine whether all of the direct children of W are identical, other than perhaps for their topmost labels. Is that right? For instance, if `A` were a large tree rather than just a leaf, every appearance of `A` in the tree you drew would need to have the exact same shape and labels?

Comment: @jacobm Yes, I suppose that might be the shortest explanation: Starting at the root (here, `W`), are all of my direct child sub-trees identical in shape and labels, except for the label on their root? Drop down to my direct children (here, `T`, `L`, and `X`), and ask each of them the same question. Then their children, etc., in essentially a breadth-first traversal, asking this question at every node.

Comment: Consider asking cs-related questions in [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the claim that short-circuiting your equality check is "far more efficient" than the enumeration strategy needs testing. If your input set isn't huge, it's unlikely to make a difference, and if it *is* huge then you probably need to measure with representative data.

That said, here's pseudocode for an algorithm that compares from left to right across all subtrees, trying to look at elements one at a time across trees rather than generating all sets up front:

```
function AllLeavesEqual(tree):
  if (tree.children.size < 2):
    return true
  subtreeIterators = [GetLeafIterator(t) for subtree in tree.children]
  baseLeaves = subtreeIterators[0]
  comparisonLeaves = subtreeIterators[1:]
  pop one item off of each iterator
  while (baseLeaves.hasNext()):
    nextLeaf = baseLeaves.next()
    for comparisonIterator in comparisonLeaves:
      if (!comparisonIterator.hasNext() or comparisonIterator.next() != nextLeaf):
        return false

  return true iff no iterator in comparisonLeaves satisfies iterator.hasNext()

function GetLabelIterator(tree):
  return Iterator:
    stack = Stack(tree)

    define next():
      t = Pop(stack)
      push each of t.children onto stack in reverse order
      return t.label

    define isEmpty():
      return stack.isEmpty()
```

What I'm doing here is just checking every label in every subtree for equality, with the trick being that rather than materialize the label set I'm using an iterator, which effectively performs a preorder traversal of each subtree lazily. You could certainly use any other method of lazy tree-node enumeration you wanted.

Note two things: First, that this traversal isn't the level-order traversal that you wanted. It's a preorder traversal instead; if it really matters to use level-order traversal then you'd need to replace the iterator I wrote above with an iterator that enumerates that way. Second, as described this algorithm doesn't check structural equality, only ordered-traversal equality. This is easy to fix if it matters.

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that the traversal order of the sub-trees would actually matter; the odds of running into a mismatch at any point in the traversal should technically be the same no matter what node in the sub-tree you start from. The only issue would be to make sure that the chosen traversal doesn't compare the roots of the sub-trees, which your pseudocode does by popping them off before beginning comparisons. I would not have thought to use Iterators - this is a clever use of what is considered, in Java, at least, to be a rather archaic object/pattern. I'll try this out tomorrow.